# Why the method QueryNode of Aerospike's Java Client only returns master objects

Tags: aerospike

I have an Aerospike cluster of size 3, my replication factor is 3. So suppose I have 10,000 objects, then every node will hold about 3,333 master objects, and 6,666 replicated objects. I have the default settings I suppose.

I realized that the **QueryNode** method of the Java Client only returns master objects on a node, so I'll always get about 1/3 of my total number of objects, even the nodes do have replicated objects on them. And further more, the **Query** method uses QueryNode to fetch results from every node.

I found this not ideal in my case: there was one time that all 3 nodes are functioning but the network connection from  1 node to the client program went down. So the **Query** method will only fetch master objects from 2 nodes, but on the server side, all 3 nodes are functioning so master objects are distributed equally, so as result, I can only fetch about 2/3 of my objects using the Query method.

I can write some initial check to verify if my network connections are all ok, but still, since every node has all objects on them (master or replicated), why only fetch the master objects?

Comment: Why would you need a query to return the number of master and prole records?

Comment: @BenBates Actually we need to fetch all records in one set. We used at first the scan, but they were too slow that we couldn't really use them.

Answer (score 2):

You should read the [Getting Started](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/query/query.html) documentation for the Java client, and its [JavaDoc reference](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/).

There is a difference between a scan and a query, unless you're using Query without a predicate (which converts into a Scan). If you intend to use a predicate you need to [create](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/client/java/usage/query/sindex.html) a [secondary index](http://www.aerospike.com/docs/architecture/secondary-index.html) over the bin you'll be querying.

Both queries and scans only return master objects. The purpose of replica objects is to be to ensure that data is not lost when a node goes down. You shouldn't expect to get back replica objects from either.

The case where you can actually read a replica object is when you change your [replica](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/Policy.html#replica) read policy to [RANDOM](http://www.aerospike.com/apidocs/java/com/aerospike/client/policy/Replica.html#RANDOM). The read may go to the master or one of the replicas, rather than to the master only (the default value is MASTER).

Comment: I'm indeed querying my set based on a bin having a secondary index. So if I need to get all records satisfying a query condition I must query all nodes alive?

Comment: You would use Query rather than QueryNode - the client sends that in parallel to all the nodes in the cluster. Similarly I wouldn't use ScanNode unless you really needed to just scan a single node for some reason (like writing a backup tool).

Comment: I'm indeed using Query, but like I said, since I only get about 2/3 of my expected results, and the network connection from 1 node to my client went down, so I assume that Query uses internally QueryNode, and that was the reason that I got 2/3 of my expected results, is my assumption right?

Comment: When a node goes down the Aerospike nodes will automatically re-cluster (once they've all noticed the heartbeats to that downed node are failing). When that happens the data will be rebalanced. During migration of data (part of rebalancing) you will get unreliable data for scan and query, which is why the policy for both allows you to fail on cluster change. You can chose that policy, and wait out the rebalancing. Or you can accept that the numbers might be off.

Answer (score 0):

Right now Aerospike provides Aerospike Java Client which takes a list of host
You need to pass all the nodes URI and port while creating the client so that it will get all the data from Secondary Index while it queries.